# Bazel Package: How to export build artifacts to another directory with external dependency?

Tags: bazel, bazel-rules

I am new to Bazel. I have a project which is built with Bazel. It also used some third-party libraries which are also build from bazel (from source).

I am now trying to export my project as a standalone library to others. I can compile my project as a so and copy related hpp files to a directory.

But I don't know how to deal with the third party libraries. Is there a fancy way to do this? Or any examples I can refer to?

My goal is to :

1. Comile the project as a so file. Copy to a specfic directory. (DONE)
2. Copy all the header files with tree structure. (DONE).
3. Copy all the external libraries into the specfic directory as well (NEED HELP)
4. Copy the external libraries' header files into the same header directory (NEED HELP)

output:

- include/

  - my_library_name/
  - third_party_name1/
  - third_party_name2/
- library/

  - libmy_library.so
  - libthird_party_name1.so
  - libthird_party_name2.so

Comment: Are your project and the third-party libraries under the same _workspace_?

Comment: You could make a genrule that takes the library objects as inputs and outputs a single tar file with all your files bundled up how you would like it deployed?

Comment: @dms
No they are not in the same workspace. I imported them in the project's WORKSPACE and use as third_party.

Comment: @Laurenz
Thanks for your suggestion. I am writing this genrule. But I am not sure how to copy the libraries. Since they are in bazel-bin/my_library_name/ & bazel-bin/external/third_party_name1.

Should I hardcode the path and copy the libraries from there? Or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: If you have control over the third-party libraries BUILD files, you can use the `pkg_tar` rules to collect the output files (can add more info in a proper answer, if that's the case)

Comment: @dms 
Yes. I have the control of the third-party libraries. and they are also built from source via Bazel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have control over the `BUILD` files of the third-party libraries, you could expose the header files separately and then use `pkg_tar` rules to collect the target files in the main project.

For example, assuming a folder structure like the following:

```
.
|-- project
|   |-- BUILD
|   |-- mylib
|   |   |-- BUILD
|   |   |-- mylib.cpp
|   |   `-- mylib.h
|   `-- WORKSPACE
`-- thirdparty
    |-- lib1
    |   |-- BUILD
    |   |-- lib1.cpp
    |   `-- lib1.h
    |-- lib2
    |   |-- BUILD
    |   |-- lib2.cpp
    |   `-- lib2.h
    `-- WORKSPACE
```

your third-party libraries BUILD files could expose a `filegroup` and a `cc_library`:

```py
# thirdparty/lib1/BUILD

filegroup(
    name = "headers",
    srcs = ["lib1.h"],
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
)

cc_library(
    name = "lib1",
    hdrs = [":headers"],
    srcs=["lib1.cpp"],
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
)
```

The same pattern will apply to `thirdparty/lib2/BUILD` and `project/mylib/BUILD`.

Now in the main project you could have a main `BUILD` script that collects all the files into a `tar` archive:

```py
# project/BUILD

load("@bazel_tools//tools/build_defs/pkg:pkg.bzl", "pkg_tar")

pkg_tar(
    name = "release_headers",
    srcs = [
        "//mylib:headers",
        "@thirdparty//lib1:headers",
        "@thirdparty//lib2:headers",
    ],
    package_dir = "include",
)

pkg_tar(
    name = "release_libs",
    srcs = [
        "//mylib",
        "@thirdparty//lib1",
        "@thirdparty//lib2",
    ],
    package_dir = "lib",
)

pkg_tar(
    name = "release",
    deps = [
        ":release_headers",
        ":release_libs",
    ],
)
```

Building `:release` should create a `tar` file with the desired structure:

```
$> bazel build :release
...
Target //:release up-to-date:
  bazel-bin/release.tar
...
```

```
$> tar -tf bazel-bin/release.tar
./
./include/
./include/mylib.h
./include/lib1.h
./include/lib2.h
./lib/
./lib/libmylib.a
./lib/libmylib.so
./lib/liblib1.a
./lib/liblib1.so
./lib/liblib2.a
./lib/liblib2.so
```

You can also have the `pkg_tar` rules for the third-party libraries in the third-party workspace for better modularity.